# SQL Query about delivery code

Tags: sql

I'm trying to created a query for *the Number of Orders waiting to be delivered*.

This involves using the `delivery_status_code` from the `customer_orders_delivery` table.

The status code includes - `Delivered`, `Processing` and `Dispatched`.

I want to select the number of orders which are processing and dispatched.

Currently I have written:

```
Select COUNT ORDER_ID 
FROM customer_orders_delivery 
WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%'OR'Processing%'
```

However, this is incorrect. Could someone please help with this query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the `count()` aggregate with a `group by`:

```
Select delivery_status_code, COUNT(ORDER_ID)
FROM customer_orders_delivery 
WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%'
  OR  delivery_status_code LIKE 'Processing%'
GROUP BY delivery_status_code
```

I added the `delivery_status_code` to the select list so you know the count for each code.

I am not sure why you are using `LIKE`, you might be able to use:

```
Select delivery_status_code, COUNT(ORDER_ID)
FROM customer_orders_delivery 
WHERE delivery_status_code IN ('Dispatched', 'Processing')
GROUP BY delivery_status_code
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the actual status code is something like 'Dispatched via DHL'.

Comment: @egrunin it is possible, that is why I included both versions of the answer.  This is a time when it would have been helpful to see some data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want your answers grouped by ORDER_ID, you don't need to mention it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NumPendingOrders, delivery_status_code
FROM customer_orders_delivery 
WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%'
OR delivery_status_code LIKE 'Processing%'
GROUP BY delivery_status_code
```

Comment: If `order_id` is unique then grouping by it will return an incorrect count.

Comment: Yes, I realized that too -- fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Order_ID)
FROM customer_orders_delivery
WHERE delivery_status_code LIKE 'Dispatched%' 
OR delivery_status_code LIKE 'Processing%'
```